# rude or abusive flag declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, offensive-flag

I have marked [code formatting - How to make Android studio put braces on own line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088758/how-to-make-android-studio-put-braces-on-own-line) as **rude or abusive**.

Why is my flag declined?

The post is showing closed on my flag summary. When I visit the URL it's unavailable.

Comment: "Fucked" and "idiot" are rude, but don't fit the criteria for truly "offensive" -- those words *might* sometimes be acceptable on the site. More importantly, the question can just be edited to remove them -- it doesn't require moderator intervention. You can't see the question because it was deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @JeremyBanks If you agree that these words are rude, FYI while flagging I see **rude or abusive** label. If they qualify **rude** then my flag shouldn't be declined.

Comment: "I have marked this post as offensive since it was containing offensive words. Why is my flag declined?" Your first mistake is in classifying a post as offensive based on a word filter.

Comment: @BoltClock Mistake? OK. Let me put it this way. Which flag should I use for the post containing such words?

Comment: There were seven flags and two mods on that post.  One of them marked the subsequent rude flags helpful.  I'll let them weigh in, if they wish to.  In the meantime, what prevented you from simply editing the offensive content out?  You do have editing privileges.

Comment: And to be clear, the only time that kind of language is appropriate on Stack Overflow is when it occurs in code, in the context of a [clbuttic filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).  It's never appropriate when it is directed at someone or some thing, which it was in this case.  My metric for "offensive" is "has this post become a distraction?"  Which it certainly has.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes you are right. I would've edited the it. Maybe there are pending edits, I don't know. But if editing is only the way, Whats the use of the flag. Shouldn't I use it in any case.

Comment: Use the flag if the OP reverts your edit, or you have insufficient rep to edit.

Comment: Since you have the ability to approve or reject edits, you also have the ability to see pending edits. There'll be a link under the question if it has a pending edit.

Comment: Why is everybody pointing edit. If I see a post **which is rude** I flag it as rude. Editing is recommended, I know, but that doesn't make my flagging useless.

Comment: I mentioned pending edits because you explicitly said *"Maybe there are pending edits, I don't know."* and I was trying to tell you how you can know if there is one.

Comment: "Don't be a jerk. [Name-calling, Bigotry of any kind, Inappropriate language or attention, and Harassment and bullying] are just a few examples. If you see them, *flag* them." http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice This part may need some clarification.

Answer (score 7):

Flags are for action that community can't perform themselves.

In this case removing fluff from the post could be easily edited out the same way one would remove "thank you" notes.

If OP would prefer to restore original language (or bad language in comments) - indeed it should be flagged. Some users just need to understand that language that looks cool in childcare and barely acceptable between in elementary school kids does not have place on SO.

Comment: Does this mean rude flags without edit attempt should be declined?

Comment: @VKK I expect flag to be declined because post should not  be flagged to start with, even if mod decide to take some action (this opinion is based on frequent comments from diamond mods, including this question). Similar to "reject and edit" in edit queue when edit is reasonable, but should not be performed by person with not enough rep.

Comment: I totally agree. This could be the answer also for this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338470/rude-flag-declined-on-question-link?noredirect=1#comment415158_338470